# Run function only once. && doesn't work in IE

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer

This function should only be able to run once, which works in Chrome and FF -- BUT In IE you can run it multiple times. How can I make it able to run only once in IE ?

```
function topSect() {
  var mouseY = 0;
  var topValue = 10;
  var executed = false;

  window.addEventListener("mouseout", function(e) {
      mouseY = e.clientY;
      if (mouseY < topValue && !executed) {
        //do something here
        executed = true;
      }
    },
    false);
};
```

Comment: What exactly is "do something"? If it throws an exception, `executed = true` will not be set.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [removeEventListener](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener) to ensure that the mouseleave is ever triggered only once.

```js
var mouseY = 0;
var topValue = 10;
var executed = false;

function mouseoutHandler(e){
  window.removeEventListener("mouseout", mouseoutHandler, false);
  mouseY = e.clientY;
  exectued = true;
  console.log(mouseY);
}

function topSect() {
  window.addEventListener("mouseout", mouseoutHandler, false);
};


topSect();
```